# Swagger API Documentation over @ApiResponse with map as responseContainer does not work

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have an endpoint that returns `Map<String,MyObject>`

```
public Response doStuff(){
  Map<String,MyObject> map = getMap();
  return Response.ok(map ).build();
}
```

With that, I tired to describe the API as following:

```
@ApiResponses({@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = MyObject.class, responseContainer = "Map[String,MyObject]")}
public Response doStuff(){
   Map<String,MyObject> map = getMap();
   return Response.ok(map ).build();
}
```

In swagger UI this only renders me the `MyObject` model as return type, ignoring the `Map` with `String` keys. 
[image]

When I declare the endpoint like (which I finally will **not** do)

```
public  Map<String,MyObject> doStuff(){
  ...
}
```

swagger ui renders the model as expected:
[image]

I wasn't able to find any useful documentation about Map as response container.

How do I declare the return model of a `Map<String,MyObject` within the `@ApiResponse` annotation?

Answer (score 0):

According to Swagger documentation, the only valid values for the responseContainer are "List", "Set" or "Map". Any other value will be ignored:
https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiOperation.html#responseContainer()

So try

```
responseContainer = "Map"
```

instead of

```
responseContainer = "Map[String,MyObject]"
```